# Centering variables in multidimensional data

Tags: regression, interaction, centering

Assume you have a panel data set, that means for each car (CAR), with several individuals (IDs), the dependent variable is given as the power (POWER) created by an engine, over time (time). Further assume we have several related independent variables, the input parameters (X1 to X10). Further assume we are interested in an interaction effect between X1 and X2.

Here is a dataset in R that displays what I mean:

```
set.seed(1);test <- data.frame(CAR=c(rep("Ford GT",100),rep("Tesla P90D",100)),ID = c(rep(1,25),rep(2,25),rep(3,25),rep(4,25)),
                           time=rep(1925:1949,4),
                           POWER=rnorm(200,mean = 5),X1=rnorm(200, mean = 1),X2=rnorm(200, mean = 1.5),
                           X3=rnorm(200, mean = 2.5),X4=rnorm(200, mean = 3),
                           X5=rnorm(200, mean = 4),X7=rnorm(200, mean = 5),
                           X8=rnorm(200, mean = 6),X9=rnorm(200, mean = 7),
                           X10=rnorm(200, mean = 8))
```

My question is, first, if I want to conduct a panel regression, how would you center the variables? The variables (i.e. the dependent variable and the independent ones) could be centered per car, or they could be centered across all cars. I am not sure which is the right approach. Secondly, would the approach change of we just looked at one time period, that is perform a single cross-sectional regression at a certain time (which includes car-dummies)?

The sources I found on this matter are contradictory; one source says that centering must be done across all groups, as otherwise, you would have a fixed effects model ([source](https://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2013-01/msg00863.html)). Another source on the other hand says that centering must be done within groups ([source](http://www.uh.edu/~bsorense/Ozer-Balli_Sorensen.pdf)) Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Hello, can a moderator pls explain why I cannot add a bounty to my question?

Comment: You should be able to.  (I am relying on the information at https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/bounty.)  Do you not see the "Start a bounty" link below and to the left of the last comment?

Comment: @whuber thanks for helping me out. No I cant see it. It's strange, because on stack overflow, I see the function. It is definitely only missing here on Cross Validated (also in my other unanswered Q)